# Using pandas to identify which are the 5 point and 10 point scale survey questions in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, survey

I have a unique situation where my dataset contains multiple survey responses that were asked on two different scales primarily - a 5 point scale and then a 10 point scale and I have consolidated all of these responses in one dataframe. Now I would like to split and create a new column in my dataframe that can tell by looking into the responses and correspondinlgy identify it it's a 5 point scale or a 10 point scale question. For a response where there are no numbers mentioned such as 1-5 scale or 1-10 scale, the output should be blank. My dataframe looks like:

```
Question_Text
on a scale of 1 â€“ 10 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1 to 10 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1-10 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1 10 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1 â€“ 5 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1 to 5 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1-5 how well would you rate the following statements.
on a scale of 1 5 how well would you rate the following statements.
please tell us how ready you feel for this (0 - 6 not ready, 6-8 somewhat ready, and 9-10 ready)
how useful did you find the todayâ€™s webinar?
```

and what I would like to achieve looks like:

```
Question_Text                                                           Type_of_Question
on a scale of 1 â€“ 10 how well would you rate the following            10 point scale
on a scale of 1 to 10 how well would you rate the following             10 point scale
on a scale of 1 to 5 how well would you rate the following              5 point scale
please tell us how ready you feel for this (0 - 6 not ready)...         10 point scale
how useful did you find the todayâ€™s webinar?

...
```

Is there any possible way to achieve this? Can a pattern be identified using regex that can take care of different sorts of inputs as I have shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming "Question_Text" the column of interest and that you only have numbers that describe the scale, you could `extractall` and get the max number to compare it to `5`. If greater, we assume it's a 10 points scale:

```
import numpy as np

num = (df['Question_Text']
       .str.extractall('(\d+)')[0]
       .astype(int)
       .groupby(level=0).max()
       .gt(5).reindex(df.index)
       )
    
df['Type_of_Question'] = np.select([num>5, num>0],
                                   ['10 point scale', '5 point scale'],
                                  np.nan)
```

Output:

```
                                                                                      Question_Text Type_of_Question
0                          on a scale of 1 â€“ 10 how well would you rate the following statements.   10 point scale
1                           on a scale of 1 to 10 how well would you rate the following statements.   10 point scale
2                              on a scale of 1-10 how well would you rate the following statements.   10 point scale
3                              on a scale of 1 10 how well would you rate the following statements.   10 point scale
4                           on a scale of 1 â€“ 5 how well would you rate the following statements.    5 point scale
5                            on a scale of 1 to 5 how well would you rate the following statements.    5 point scale
6                               on a scale of 1-5 how well would you rate the following statements.    5 point scale
7                               on a scale of 1 5 how well would you rate the following statements.    5 point scale
8  please tell us how ready you feel for this (0 - 6 not ready, 6-8 somewhat ready, and 9-10 ready)   10 point scale
9                                                    how useful did you find the todayâ€™s webinar?              nan
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this. But if I am not wrong this will not work if my question_text column has a string that has no numbers in it. I have edited my input dataframe. Have a look at the last row. In such a scenario I am happy if nothing is returned. Can something be done?

Comment: See update to the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can check to see if `5` or `10` exists in your column and create the new column based on that:

```
df["Type_of_Question"] = df.Question_Text.apply(lambda x: "10 point scale" if "10" in x else "5 point scale")
print(df)

                               

    Question_Text Type_of_Question
0  on a scale of 1 â€“ 10 how well would you rate...   10 point scale
1  on a scale of 1 to 10 how well would you rate ...   10 point scale
2  on a scale of 1-10 how well would you rate the...   10 point scale
3  on a scale of 1 10 how well would you rate the...   10 point scale
4  on a scale of 1 â€“ 5 how well would you rate ...    5 point scale
5  on a scale of 1 to 5 how well would you rate t...    5 point scale
6  on a scale of 1-5 how well would you rate the ...    5 point scale
7  on a scale of 1 5 how well would you rate the ...    5 point scale
8  please tell us how ready you feel for this (0 ...   10 point scale
```